# I have prevented form submission using jquery. How Can I submit form again without removing my current code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have prevented form submission using jquery. How Can I submit form again without removing my current code ?

```
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: `$(".form-horizontal").submit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Js**

```
$('.form-horizontal').get(0).submit()
```

**OR Using Flag**

```
var preventForm = true;
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function(e) {
  if (preventForm) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Set `preventForm = false` before you submit

Answer (score 0):

Without further context it's hard to answer, but you could add a click handler to the submit button which sends an http request to the form endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have found solution.